# Is there a better alternative to std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any> to have a map of strings to any type of value?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a Log function that outputs to the console. The syntax that I eventually want to use would look like this:

```
Log(Info, 
    "Message", 
    { {"Key1", value1},
      {"Key2", value2} })
```

Where `value1` and `value2` may not be of the same type (maybe a std::string for a name and an int their age). Is there a better approach that using `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any>` to store the key value pairs and using `std::any_cast` to deduce the type before outputting to the console?

Comment: how about void* ?

Comment: `std::any` won't work, there's no way to print it. I'd use `std::vector` with a class as the element type, this class having a template constructor (with two parameters, a string and  templated one).

Comment: It's not quite the interface you want, but [a template-based approach](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72fcf04592400899) could avoid the need for a heterogeneous container at all.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Make an answer, I like it more than the map approach.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of possible types is limited, use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead of `std::any`, eg

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::variant<int, std::string, etc>>
```

You can query a `std::variant` for the type it currently holds, via [`std::variant::index()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index) or [`std::holds_alternative()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative), and then retrieve the value via [`std::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) (using `index()` with `get()` would be useful in a `switch()` block, for instance).  Or, you can use [`std::get_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if) to get a pointer to the data if it matches a given type.

Or, you can use [`std::visit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), which would be useful in a logging use-case, as you could provide separate visitors to log each possible type as needed.

Comment: Even better yet, do not store heterogeneous data in containers. The need for this is extremely rare. Also, I think you need to elaborate how to properly use index with get, since most straightforward approach `get<index>` would obviously fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <sstream>

struct LogPair{
    template<typename T>
    LogPair(std::string_view key, T&& value){
        std::stringstream buffer;
        //Feel free to change
        buffer<<key <<": "<<std::forward<T>(value);
        msg = buffer.str();
    }

    std::string msg;
};

enum class LogLevel{
    Info = 0,
};
void log(LogLevel level, std::string_view msg, std::initializer_list<LogPair> args){
    (void)level;//TODO
    std::cout<<msg<<'\n';
    for(const LogPair& s: args)
        std::cout<<'\t'<<s.msg<<'\n';
}

struct Test{//Complex type with custom print
    float val;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t){
        os<<t.val;
        return os;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main(){
    int value1 = 10;
    Test value2{1.4};
    
    log(LogLevel::Info,"Message", { {"Key1", value1},{"Key2", value2} });
}
```

Output:

```
Message 
    Key1: 10
    Key2: 1.4
```

The perfect solution would be akin to the one posted by @Miles Budnek:

```
template <typename... Params>
void Log(LogLevel level, std::string_view message, const Params&... params);
```

Or with pairs:

```
template <typename... Params>
void Log(LogLevel level, std::string_view message, const std::pair<std::string_view,Params>&... params)
```

But neither case will compile with this:

```
Log(level, "Msg", {"Key1",value1},{"Key2", value2})
```

This is required: (@Miles used a tuple)

```
Log(level, "Msg", std::pair{"Key1",10},std::pair{"Key2", 1.2})
```

The reason is that even though we can see that `Params` should be deduced to `int,double`, the compiler does not because the brace syntax is not deducible. Deduction guides are no help here (even if we remade it into a Log constructor) since there is really no way how to match the brace syntax since it does not even have a type.  I do not believe there is a solution to it with variadic templates.

But, the syntax you provided can lead to a solution. The only hope is to convert the brace initializer syntax to `std::initializer_list<T>`, but what T? It should look like `std::pair<std::string_view,?>` but each pair is different. Here, you could use `std::any` and it would work, there is an easier way.

Create a **non-templated** class `LogPair` with a **templated constructor** that can accept a brace initializer syntax matching any pair!

```
template<typename T> LogPair(std::string_view key, T&& value);
```

That's almost it, now log can accept `std::initializer_list<LogPair>` because it matches the syntax correctly and incorrect usage will lead to compile-time errors.

Now, the tempting this is to do the printing in the constructor, but the order of creation of these variables in unspecified and it would also precede the message print. So, the solution is to save it to a string printed later.

Note, that it is not possible to save the values in `LogPair` without reusing or reimplementing `std::any`. But that should not be required.